# Google Analytics APIs - How can I obtain landing page path list?

Tags: google-analytics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buR59.png)

I implemented a web service which provides a google analytics data using Google Analytics APIs(Reporting&Management). My service can create a **Segment** for only querying by landing page path. To input a landing page path, users need to search a list of landing page paths created by themselves. Actually, on the web page of Google Analytics, if we enter some text, we can see the list of landing page path like the image above. How can I get the list of landing page path using Google Analytics APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Make a query for it using the API.

[image: Landing Page Path]